# Disable a function on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function being regularly invoked by `setInterval`. Is it possible to disable that function on click, *without* cancelling the interval with `clearInterval`?

So say I have a function:

```
function disable(){
    alert("hello");
}
```

and it is being called in a set interval like this:

```
window.setInterval(function () {
    disable();
},1000);
```

Can I stop the `disable` function from functioning on click?

```
$("#foo").click(function () {
//disable the disable function
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the function as well, thus disabling it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#foo").click(function () {
        window["disable"] = function() {
            //aborted
        };
    });
});
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/QMuNK/). (watch the console)

Comment: Not easily, but you can store the original function elsewhere then restore it when needed.

Answer (score 4):

Capture the return value of [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) (this is the interval id). Pass it as an argument to [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearInterval).

Comment: Exactly this. You don't "disable the function", you disable the interval which calls the function.

Comment: which I definitely do not want!

Comment: @Maximilian — Why not?

Comment: I am using ajax to request data to do with this. I can't have different intervals running miliseconds out of time.

Comment: If you need millisecond accuracy, you shouldn't be using JavaScript intervals in the first place (they aren't that precise), nor should you be using Ajax (because network latency will cause delays).

Comment: YES huge seperate matter, that is seperately doing my head in haha

Comment: what would you recommend? though instead of ajax

Comment: have a look at my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21896909/a-smoother-chat-application/21897208?noredirect=1#comment33161914_21897208) earlier

Comment: Since I don't know what the problem being solved by Ajax is, I couldn't suggest anything. If a network is involved, then you are probably stuck and might need to look at removing the need for real time processing instead of trying to find a way to get it.

Comment: Have you seen my previous comment?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var timer= window.setInterval(function () {
disable();
},1000);

$("#foo").click(function(){
clearInterval(timer);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
var timer;
timer = window.setInterval(function () {
 disable();
},1000);

$("#foo").click(function () {
   //disable the disable function
    clearInterval(timer);
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Without disabling the interval!

That's the wrong way of solving this, you should be clearing the interval and then restoring it if you want to resume executing the function.

If you *really* want to do this without clearing the interval, you're after a completely vanilla `if` statement. You can't "disable" functions, you just have to conditionally choose not to execute the function's body.

```
function myFunc() {
  if (myFunc.disabled) return;

  ...
}

myFunc.disabled = false;

setInterval(myFunc, 1000);

// to disable the function:
myFunc.disabled = true;
```